# In Gradle: How to properly inherits a build-in Configuration to a new custom one

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

When I tried to take a **test run** with this *build-script* it gave me an **ERROR: *java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError***, But if I change it from **nativesOS** into **runtimeOnly** inside of this *dependencies block* it works fine.

If I proceed with this build-script do I have to manually add this *"applicationDefaultJvmArgs"* and insert the native path? If possible is there any other way to properly inherit this **runtimeOnly config** to the new one, instead of adding some boiler-plated functionality again?

```
val nativesOS : Configuration by configurations.creating {
    this.isTransitive = false
    this.extendsFrom(configurations.runtimeOnly.get())
}
dependencies {
    implementation(platform("org.lwjgl:lwjgl-bom:3.2.3"))
    ...
    // I want this one
    nativesOS("org.lwjgl","lwjgl$lib", "3.2.3",  classifier = "natives-windows")

    // I don't want this, cuz it's like losing the purpose of creating a new config, but never the less it works in the meantime.
    // runtimeOnly("org.lwjgl","lwjgl$lib", "3.2.3",  classifier = "natives-windows")

    // this is test kit I'm using, is this the reason I could run a test without the needs of
    // modifying some args in JVM.
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.1")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
    ...
}
tasks.withType(Test::class) {
    this.useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

> NOTE: I added an explicit version found at the dependency on ***natives-windows*** because it will not work if I do extract/unzip it. For some reason, the Platform/BOM-file did not work in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

All I need is to swap it:

```
val nativesOS : Configuration by configurations.creating {
    this.isTransitive = false

    // from like this,
    // this.extendsFrom(configurations.runtimeOnly.get())
    
    // into like this,
    configurations.runtimeOnly.get().extendsFrom(this)
}
```

Then take another test run, this will not make an error in this kind of situation/project.